# How can I remove a deleted custom domain from app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I previously added and verified a custom domain "foo.club" and "www.foo.club" (fake examples) to my app engine project.

I let foo.club lapse and so that domain no longer exists. However I cannot remove the domain (or the www) version from the app engine custom domain list.

When I try (in Settings/Custom domains), the 'trashcan' icon is disabled and there is a red exclamation point next to the domain that say "Certificate activation has failed. DNS records could not be found." This last point is expected since the domain does not exist.

There's also an informational box that says "All domains mapped to this application are shown below. Only owners of a domain may remove one of its mappings." I'm not sure if that box always exists or is speficially trying to explain why I can't delete the custom domain.

Regardless, I am the only user in my GCP project and I am the owner of the GCP project (and I was previously the owner of the now-deleted domain).

Further, this domain is no longer present in the list at "https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home".

When I try from the commandline, I get:

```
> gcloud app domain-mappings delete 'foo.club' --verbosity=debug
Error Response: [13] Error deleting the managed certificate for this domain mapping.
```

(no other useful error messages)

How can I remove this domain from my appengine project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.domainMappings/delete):

> A user must be authorized to administer the associated domain in order
> to delete a `DomainMapping` resource.

This means that you must be a domain owner from Google's point of view in order to manage that domain mapping.

If the domain no longer appears in the verified domains in the [webmaster central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home), it means Google does not consider that account as owner of the domain, and that account will not be able to delete the domain mapping.

I guess there are a few options to move forward:

- Just leave the domain mapping there
- Re-purchase the domain and re-verify your ownership
- Open a support ticket with GCP (if you have a support package). Not sure this option will work, but it's worth a try.